# Beautiful Soup scrapes only half table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn how to use Beautiful Soup and I have a problem when scraping a table from Wikipedia.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2

wiki = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

print soup
```

It seems like I can't get the full Wikipedia table, but the last entry I get with this code is `Omnicon Group` and it stops before getting the `/tr` in the source code. If you check in the original link the last entry of the table is `Zoetis` so it stops about half way.

Everything seems ok in the Wikipedia source code... Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I get the whole page with this code.

Comment: As do I, I also retrieve the whole page when replacing the lxml parser with the html.parser

Comment: so weird, I tried different things and I don't...It should work for me too...I have no clue!

Comment: I hope my answer helps you out

Comment: the code you posted is not enough, how do you parse the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. read this for more http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import urlopen

wiki = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'

page = urlopen(wiki)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

result = soup.find("table", class_="wikitable")

print(result)
```

this should be the last `<tr>` in your result

```
<tr>
    <td><a class="external text" href="https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:ZTS" rel="nofollow">ZTS</a></td>
    <td><a href="/wiki/Zoetis" title="Zoetis">Zoetis</a></td>
    <td><a class="external text" href="http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=ZTS&amp;action=getcompany" rel="nofollow">reports</a></td>
    <td>Health Care</td>
    <td>Pharmaceuticals</td>
    <td><a href="/wiki/Florham_Park,_New_Jersey" title="Florham Park, New Jersey">Florham Park, New Jersey</a></td>
    <td>2013-06-21</td>
    <td>0001555280</td>
</tr>
```

You will also need to install requests with `pip install requests` and i used

```
python==3.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I tried your code but it says "No module named request". If I substitute urllib.request with urllib2 the code runs but it still stops at the same point. I have python 3.5

Comment: pip install request to get module sorry i didnt mention that

Comment: it worked. I still have no idea why my code was stopping half way, but after installing the lxml and the request module this worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is my working answer. It should work for you without even installing lxml.
I used Python 2.7

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
wiki = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print soup.table
```